# vm runInNewContext not executing the code while using module _compile does

Tags: node.js

I am using the following code to execute a string on the fly in node code written in typescript

```js
import path from 'path';
import { Module } from 'module';

const getNodeModulesLookupPath = (filename: string) => {
  let dir = path.dirname(filename);
  return (Module as any)._nodeModulePaths(dir);
};

export const runCode = (code: string, fileName: string) => {
  let mod = new Module(fileName, module.parent as any);
  mod.filename = fileName;
  mod.paths = getNodeModulesLookupPath(fileName);
  (mod as any)._compile(code, fileName);
};
```

If I execute this code, I can see the console.log

```js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var cucumber_1 = require("cucumber");
var And = cucumber_1.When;
// globals for now
var left = 0;
var right = 0;
var result = 0;
cucumber_1.Given('I take the number {int}', function (n) {
    left = Number(n);
});
cucumber_1.When('I take the number {int}', function (n) {
    right = Number(n);
});
And('I add them', function () {
    result = left + right;
});
cucumber_1.Then('I will have {int}', function () {
    console.log("the result is " + result);
});
```

But if I use `vm` from node and `runInNewContext`, I don't see the output of the console.log

```js
import vm from 'vm';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
export const runCode = (code: string, fileName: string) => {
  console.log(code);
  vm.runInNewContext(code, { exports: {}, module: {}, require: require });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see logs of code that will be handled by virtual machine in your console you should pass your `console` instance to virtual machine in same fashion like you passed `require`, `module` and `exports`.

try this code

```js
import vm from 'vm';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
export const runCode = (code: string, fileName: string) => {
  console.log(code);
  vm.runInNewContext(code, { exports: {}, module: {}, require: require, console: console });
};
```